# How to decode json that has dynamic key values in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a little trouble constructing my Codable model correctly in swift. I have a json that can have dynamic id key values and one key value that I know is always the same. How do I deal with the dynamic id values? From my research, it looks like I need a custom decoder init, but I don't believe I am doing it 100% correctly. Thank you.

Example json:

```
{
  "1f73433230": "Clark Kent",
  "f1c3432fd6": "Batman",
  "3d34457d69": "Wonder Woman",
  "OTHER_ID": "Other"
}
```

Code

```
struct SuperHeroIds: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let otherId: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case otherID = "OTHER_ID"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        otherId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .otherID)
        
        id = String()
      
        ???
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish, from your code it looks like you are only interested in the id values?

Comment: Should be noted that one should execute this task whilst not drunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom CodingKey

```swift
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    enum Errors: Error {
        case invalid
    }

    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        self.intValue = Int(stringValue)
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }

    static func key(named name: String) throws -> Self {
        guard let key = Self(stringValue: name) else {
            throw Errors.invalid
        }
        return key
    }
}
```

and decode in `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` like so:

```swift
struct SuperHeroIds: Decodable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let otherId: String
    let idToHeroMap: [String:String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case otherID = "OTHER_ID"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        otherId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .otherID)
        
        id = String()
      
        let heroContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        // all keys that not decoded with CodingKeys
        let decodedKeys = CodingKeys.allCases.map({ $0.rawValue })
        let filteredKeys = heroContainer.allKeys.filter({ !decodedKeys.contains($0.stringValue) })
        
        // fill idToHeroMap
        var result = [String:String](minimumCapacity: filteredKeys.count)
        for key in filteredKeys  {
            result[key.stringValue] = try heroContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: key)
        }
        
        self.idToHeroMap = result
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Kirow, thank you. When I tried this,  it says: "Type 'ResponseData.CodingKeys' has no member 'allCases'"

Comment: add `CaseIterable` to `CodingKeys`

Comment: Now it says: "Type 'ResponseData.AnyKey' does not conform to protocol 'CaseIterable'

Comment: @drunkiosdeveloper updated code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from:data)
```